# Django forms.MultiValueField with widget set to widget.MultiWidget; proper way to do validation?

Tags: jquery, django

Multi-form widgets allow us to have some hidden fields as _0 _1, etc instead of .  This all works great until your forms.MultiValueField needs to start throwing ValidationError() in the clean() methods.

Infact... ValidationError() sets the form error as  instead of _0 or whatever...

Rather then write an 'if' wrapper in every single view to catch and swap this fieldname to _0... is there a cleaner way i can do this in the MultiWidget or MultiValueField?

I tried throwing: ValidationError({'myfieldname_0': ['my error',]})  within the MultiValueField clean() function, but when it's caught at a higher level, it just saves 'my_error' back into the self._errors of the form under in the 'myfieldname' hash (without the _0).  It seems to be cleaned up that way in 'site-packages/django/forms/forms.py' The other problem with this approach anyway is it requires me to hardcode 'myfieldname' which i don't want to do.

In short, I want to make use to MultiWidget to make forms simple and easy to manage, but I want validation to add the _0 in the hash response for this field (at the end of the field name) to match the actual input records that are put in.  This makes it much easier to integrate jquery.validation() (http://jqueryvalidation.org/). I'm also open to accepting the bad design... perhaps I just need the MutilValueField and not a MutilWidget *shrugs*.

Below is a sample code setting up my problem:

```
from django.forms import MultiWidget
from django.forms import MultiValueField
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.forms import widgets

class MyWidget(MultiWidget):
    """

    """
    def __init__(self, attrs=None, **kwargs):

        # Populated once render() is called
        self.name = u''

        _widgets = (
            widgets.TextInput(attrs=attrs),
            widgets.HiddenInput(attrs=None),
            widgets.HiddenInput(attrs=None),
        )
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(_widgets, attrs=None, **kwargs)

    def value_from_datadict(self, data, files, name):
        return [ widget.value_from_datadict(data, files, name + '_%s' % i)
                     for i, widget in enumerate(self.widgets)]

class MyFormField(MultiValueField):
    """
    Significantly simplified just to show my problem
    """
    widget = MyWidget

    def clean(self, value):
        # I want to some how alter how this exception is thrown so it isn't put in
        # the self._errors['<fieldname>'] hash, but instead placed in 
        # the self._errors['<fieldname>'_0] hash

        raise ValidationError(self.error_messages['required'])

class MyForm(ModelForm):
    """
   Simple form example of how I'd use the field
    """
    class Meta:
        model = <some model>

    performer = MyFormField(
        max_length=100,
        required=True,
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by altering the default actions of the MultiWidget like this:

```
from django.forms import MultiWidget as DjangoMultiWidget
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

class MultiWidget(DjangoMultiWidget):
    """
    This widget djusts the extends the existing MultiWidget to not
    place an _<index> on the first widget

    Hence a list of 3 widgets would look like:

        <input name="fieldname"/>
        <input name="fieldname_0"/>
        <input name="fieldname_1"/>

    """

    def __init__(self, *attrs, **kwargs):

        # Populated once render() is called
        self.name = u''

        super(MultiWidget, self).__init__(*attrs, **kwargs)


    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        """
        We over-ride this so we can correctly extract the name

        """

        # Save Name
        self.name = name

        if self.is_localized:
            for widget in self.widgets:
                widget.is_localized = self.is_localized
        # value is a list of values, each corresponding to a widget
        # in self.widgets.
        if not isinstance(value, list):
            value = self.decompress(value)
        output = []
        final_attrs = self.build_attrs(attrs)
        id_ = final_attrs.get('id', None)

        # First Entry is not prefixed with underscore (_)
        try:
            widget_value = value[0]
        except IndexError:
            widget_value = None
        output.append(self.widgets[0].render(name, widget_value, final_attrs))

        # now we process the rest
        for i, widget in enumerate(self.widgets[1:]):
            try:
                widget_value = value[i]
            except IndexError:
                widget_value = None
            if id_:
                final_attrs = dict(final_attrs, id='%s_%s' % (id_, i))
            output.append(widget.render(name + '_%s' % i, widget_value, final_attrs))
        return mark_safe(self.format_output(output))

    def format_output(self, rendered_widgets):
        """
        Place an error class
        """
        return u''.join(rendered_widgets) + \
                u'<div class="error" for="id_%s" style="display: none;"></div>' % self.name


    def value_from_datadict(self, data, files, name):
        return [ self.widgets[0].value_from_datadict(data, files, name) ] + \
                [ widget.value_from_datadict(data, files, name + '_%s' % i)
                    for i, widget in enumerate(self.widgets[1:]) ]
```

There is no magic going on here as the majority of the code is taken right out of /django/forms/fields.py

However using the field this way allows you to throw the standard exception without the _0 but it actually references the field content is stored in:

```
<input name="fieldname"/>
<input name="fieldname_0"/>
<input name="fieldname_1"/>
```

Instead of the default MultiWidget style:

```
<input name="fieldname_0"/>
<input name="fieldname_1"/>
<input name="fieldname_2"/>
```

The end result is Django's framework and Error Handling becomes 100% compatible with JQuery's validation plugin (which is mentioned in my question).

Hopefully this answer helps people in the future!

Answer (score 0):

You can also catch exceptions in the compress method of the MultiValueField, which would allow you to add an exception for the field as a whole. I maintain a [Feet and Inches form widget](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2327/) that extends MultiValueField as well.

The init and compress portions are:

```
class FeetAndInchesField(MultiValueField):
    widget = FeetAndInchesWidget

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        errors = self.default_error_messages.copy()
        if 'error_messages' in kwargs:
            errors.update(kwargs['error_messages'])
        localize = kwargs.get('localize', False)
        fields = (
            IntegerField(min_value=0, required=False, localize=localize),
            IntegerField(min_value=0, localize=localize),
            FloatField()
        )
        super(FeetAndInchesField, self).__init__(fields, *args, **kwargs)

    def compress(self, data_list):
        if data_list:
            feet = data_list[0]
            inches = data_list[1]
            fractional_inches = data_list[2]
            if feet == inches == fractional_inches == 0:
                raise ValidationError(u'Please specify a value for feet or inches')
            return sum_feet_inches_fractional_inches(feet, inches, fractional_inches)
        return None
```

This should allow you to raise an exception for all or a combination of fields, instead of one at a time. Hope that helps you out.

Comment: Thank you for your input! I had no idea i could throw an exception there too.  But i guess the problem is i want the ValidationError to raise an exception on the field 'fieldname_0' and not 'fieldname'.  This is easy to do in the form class (i could just override the is_valid() function.  But i wanted to try to accomplish this at the widget or field level so i wouldn't have to repeat the same code for every form I use the widget for. I'm not sure if that makes sense or not.

Comment: You wouldn't have to repeat the same code over and over - that's what inheritance is for :) You can always extend a Form or ModelForm that has the fields you need and also the clean methods in one place.

Comment: Thanks again for your speedy replies. Your advice is great, but it just doesn't raise the ValidationError using the custom form input widget (suffixed with _0 or _1) which is my goal.  Modifying the form through inheritance isn't an option because i have some forms with 2 of these widgets, and some with 3 and 4.  So i might as well just write a custom form for each one if i go that route. I'll just keep plugging away at different things before i give up and go the form route.